# What are the differences between MATLAB LIBSVM and fitcsvm in MATLAB Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox”

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I get confused with SVM on MATLAB. There are Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox as well as other libraries like LibSVM. I wonder what makes them different and which one should I use,

I wanted to implement SVM on my dataset. Which tool should I use?

fitcsvm - Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox
https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machine-classification.html

LibSVM
https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

I'm also wondering why there other SVM libraries while MATLAB has provided their own tool

Comment: People might make their own because: 1) it’s better, 2) MATLAB’s didn’t exist when they made it, 3) MATLAB’s costs money, 4) they have a library and it’s easy to interface it to MATLAB, 5) ...

Comment: What I’m trying to say is that this question should be directed at the people that wrote libsvm, only they know why they made it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'MATLAB’s costs money'? Because LibSVM is also for MATLAB

Comment: I'm asking because I don'tknow which one should I use and which one is the best

Comment: You pay a license to use MATLAB, and you pay an additional license for each of the toolboxes that are sold with MATLAB. Maybe you are at a University and have a campus license, but not everyone has that privilege. Toolboxes made by third parties can be free. I just assume LibSVM is free, because the link you post is from a University.

Comment: If this is indeed the case, then one big difference (without knowing anything about functionality) is that the Statistics Toolbox comes with great customer service, whereas the tool you can download for free from a University website likely doesn't.

Comment: I see. Now it makes sense